# Upper bound for nth power of a sum - sum of nth powers ??

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, inequality

Is there any upper bound for the following expression?

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i\right)^k-\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i^k$$

where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $k\geq1$.

Comment: $$
\infty \ \ \
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$x = \max(x_i)$
then

$\begin{array}\\
f(k)
&=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)^k-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^k\\
&=x^k((\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i/x))^k-\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i/x)^k)\\
&\le x^k(n^k-1)\\
\end{array}
$

I know that
this is a trivial bound,
but I don't see how 
to get anything better
without knowing anything
about the $x_i$.

Comment: Mean inequalities give $(\sum x_i)^k\le N^{k-1}\sum x_i^k$ so that $f(k)\le (N^{k-1}-1)\sum x_i^k\le (N^k-N)x^k$, which is a little smaller, but not substantially so.

Comment: Thank you Marty and Lutz. And about $x_i$s, assume that $\{x_i \in \mathbb{R} | 0 \leq x_i \leq 1 \}$